# openCV Thresholding negative values

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to calculate motion optical flow and I am trying to reduce noise, by thresholding smaller values. When calculating the motion flow, I also get negative values, which I would want to keep, but which get discarded once I apply the threshold.

I have thought of using the absolute value in order to achieve this, but the, how would I get back my negatives?

Also, I am using numpy arrays, if that helps:

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(frameGray, frame1Gray, 0.5,1,3,15,3,5,1)

thresh_flow = cv2.threshold(np.absolute(flow), 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy offers very powerful [indexing capabilities](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean). One of these is indexing using Boolean arrays. You can assign elements matching a condition to a certain value, which appears to be what you want. For example,

```
threshold = 2
flow[np.abs(flow) < threshold] = 0
```

will assign each element in `flow` whose absolute value is too close to zero. Supposing that `flow` looked like this:

```
[ 1  2  3]
[-1 -2 -3]
```

The result of applying this operation would be:

```
[0  2  3]
[0 -2 -3]
```

Which has correctly removed positive and negative elements with a small magnitude, but retaining the sign of the negative elements.